# Add property based on condition

Tags: c#

I am working on a csharp class and conditionally trying to hide a property based on condition in parameter. if showphone is true, I am trying not to add phone property to class. Any pointer on approach. I tried taking 2 methods separately based on the showphone case which may not be best solution.

```
public static school studying(bool showphone = false) =>
            new student
            {
                name = x.name,
                address = x.address,
                phone = x.phone     //do not add this if showphone = true            
            };
```

Comment: Are you talking about actually having the property in `Student`? Or are you talking about not storing a value? If it's the former, then you can't do that without having a different class that doesn't define `phone`.

Comment: I am trying to not have the property and assignment dynamically.

Comment: Then you will need a `Student` base class, and a `StudentWithPhoneNumber` derived class (or some other way of expressing this). Then you'll be able to return an instance of the correct class depending on whether `showphone` is true or false. C# is a statically typed language, so you can't just add or remove properties from an object like you might in say Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Classes often have properties that go unused. If a student doesn't have a phone, leave it null or `string.Empty`.

Your code that interacts with the class can check if there is a phone.

`if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(student.Phone))` will be true if the phone was set.